# how do i pass groupby elements as lists to a function in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, group-by

i am trying to generate a new column of data from an existing one in a DataFrame. However, my function is not being passed the right information. Not sure how to rectify this issue.

```
masterframe =DataFrame() # contains column ud and column Symbol

masterframe['new'] = masterframe.groupby('Symbol').ud.apply(streak)

def streak(series): 

    count = 1
    x = [1,]

    for item in range(1,len(series)):
        if series[item] == series[item-1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
        x.append(count)

    return x
```

the error i am getting is KeyError: 1L

Comment: DataFrame() is empty so it doesn't contain anything...

Answer (score -1):

Pandas uses label based indexing by default, so when you write `series[item]`, it's looking up the value `item` in the index of `series`.  To use location based index, use `.iloc`, like this.

```
    if series.iloc[item] == series.iloc[item-1]:
```

Comment: thanks vm- this gets rid of the error, but it still seems like my values are not being passed to the function. I am getting returned NaN  for every element of 'new'

Comment: Try adding a `print` to prove to yourself they are getting passed.  Your other problem is that your function returns a list, try wrapping in a series (i.e. `pd.Series(x)`) in the function return.

Comment: using print was useful- it shows that the function is returning the right data, but for some reason cannot recombine the data back into the parent frame.